# Windows 10 mobile broadband turned off

Tags: windows, windows-10, modem

Since Windows 10 version 1904 I'm not able to use my mobile broadband modem, I'm using SIM7912G module and it works fine with Windows 10 prior 1904, however, in newer releases it seems that mobile broadband is turned off no matter what you do:

[image: Turned off connection]

I've tried to reinstall drivers, enable/disable airplane mode, changed modem PID to MBIM, checked if there is any function in my laptop/virtual machine that disable mobile broadband connection and nothing seems to work.

Have you detected this issue in Windows 10? Anybody knows a solution?... I'm able to connect using AT commands, however it seems to use an old RAS connection that I don't want to use.

Also checked that windows changed modem.sys driver in version 1904, do you know any reason for this problem?

[image: NEW modem.sys driver]

[image: modem.sys driver before windows 1904]

Thanks

Comment: You might try replacing the newer driver from the previous version.  Save a backup of the driver obviously if you do that.  1904 doesn’t exist you likely mean 1903.

Comment: If the mobile modem precedes Windows 10 (2015) it may not be compliant. I upgrade my own modem at V1803 with a HUAWEI modem then that works great now.

Comment: Yeah, it is 1903, your are right. However, can I replace driver?? I think it is a driver provider by microsoft and cannot replace it directly cause I don't have permission to write over it even being administrator